# Node.js (Express API): req.body.myobject is undefined and not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, express

I have my server side in **NodeJS (ExpressJS)** which implements a POST method that should get the object I'm sending from the client and do things with it:

```
router.route('/email')
// create a mail (accessed at POST http://localhost:8080/api/email)
.post(function(req, res) {
    var email = req.body.email;
    // do things with email...
    // but it's complaining because it says it's 'undefined'
});
```

`req.body.email` should be a JSON object with this structure:

```
{"destinatary": "my@example.com", "subject": "mysubject", "message": "mymessage"}
```

I've implemented a very simple web client using **jQuery** to test my API, where the AJAX call it's done like this:

```
function sendEmail(email) {
  $.post(MYAPP.service_uri+"/email",
    email,
    function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
}
```

In the client side, `email` is an object, so it's not `undefined`... but I'm getting everytime the following error on the server side:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'destinatary' of undefined`

Comment: @Tushar I'm sending the JSON object in the body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're not sending over anything called `email` - you're attaching an object with variable name `email`

To fix your AJAX call you can do:

```
$.post(MYAPP.service_uri+"/email",
    {email: email}, //OBJECT, KEYVAL PAIR
    function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    }
);
```

Your object in your original code will be stored in plain `req.body` - not `req.body.email`

If you don't want to fix the AJAX call, you can fix the server:

```
router.route('/email')
// create a mail (accessed at POST http://localhost:8080/api/email)
.post(function(req, res) {
    var email = req.body;
});
```

Either one will work.

Comment: Totally... I was missing that! By getting `req.body` it worked. Thank you!